# Static Dropout Layer - Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dropout

I am interested in making a "dropout like" layer that is static throughout the course of training and testing, in keras. Unlike normal dropout, I only want to sever a certain amount of random weights, not the entire node. I.e. certain neurons cannot connect to others and will never be able to. Is creating a custom layer the easiest way to achieve this? Here is my current [progress](https://github.com/jordanott/No-Weight-Sharing/blob/master/CustomLayers/Biology.py).

I would also like to be able to visualize the dropout mask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to edit any source code. Just use `seed` parameter as given [here](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout).